# Transitive group of $S_6$ isomorphic to $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

What would be one example of such a group? I'm wondering if $S_3$ itself could be such an example?

Comment: By $S_3$ "itself", I assume you mean the subgroup permuting $\{1,2,3\}$? But this could not be transitive!

Comment: This is Cayley's Theorem.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Cayley's theorem certainly proves the existence of such a subgroup, but I assume the OP wants to explicitly write it down.

Comment: OK, well we could take the group generated by $(1,2,3)(4,5,6)$ and $(1,4)(2,6)(3,5)$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: why can't $S_3$ be transitive? If it acts on the set $\{1,2,3\}$ by $\sigma \cdot a := \sigma(a)$ then for any $a, b\in X$ there always exists a $\sigma \in S_3$ such that $\sigma(a)=b$.